# Applet executing program on server

Tags: java, security, process, applet, runtime.exec

I've got an applet, which has to `exec` a program on the same server.

```
Runtime c = Runtime.getRuntime();
window.finishedQuery("Got Runtime...");
Process p = c.exec(String.format("cmd");
window.finishedQuery("Excecuted CMD");
```

2nd line doesn't work in the browser, but in the Netbeans applet viewer it does.

`window` is my applet, and it does show `got runtime` but not `excecuted CMD`.

In Google chrome I see the following message:

```
access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "<<ALL FILES>>" "execute")
```

I guess the applet "thinks" that I want to get access to the users PC/programs, but I want to *start a program on the server.*

What do I have to do?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "does not work"? How do you know? What do you expect to see, and what actually happens?

Comment: well, window is my applet, and it does show "got runtime" but not "excecuted CMD", i dont know how to show more details...i guess the applet "thinks" that i want to get access to the users PC/programms, but i want to start a programm on the server :S

Comment: okay, in google chrome i see the following message
"access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "<<ALL FILES>>" "execute")"

Answer (score 2):

If created by the applet, the `Process` will be created in the JVM of the *client machine.*  That VM will not be able to call methods on the server.

The best way to approach this is to have the sand-boxed applet call home to a web-service (servlet, JSP, PHP, ASP..) on the same host it comes from.  Have the web-service create the `Process`<sup>1</sup>, and provide the output to the applet for consumption/display.

1.
Also, go through the Java World article linked from the [runtime.exec Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info) & implement all the recommendations, but for 1.5+ use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the `Process`.

Comment: To get you right:
I have to write a second applet which implements the process. I call the second applet from the first applet and get the results from there? Do i have to grant any rights to one of the applets?
Is there no easier way?

Comment: No I did not mean two applets, see the update.  Have you been through the Java World article yet?  Show the updated code as an edit to the question.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help, i found a tutorial for creating services in java, i'll try these...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i wrote a service to create the process and created a "client-class" via wsimport...everything works fine in netbeans applet manager, but when i start the applet in my browser, the applet doesnt request the service, even when i put my applett on a local webserver(xampp) and start the service on the same client. i thought if both are on the same client, i dont have to sign my applet?
(note sure if i have to make this a new question or an answer to my question...)